# Is there something wrong with my formula?

Tags: java, math

My code calculates the average height of a child once they become adult using their parents heights

I am getting height for the child being 7 feet+ when the mother and father are between 4-6 feet

> Hmale_child = ((Hmother * 13 / 12) + Hfather ) / 2
>
> Hfemale_child = ((Hfather * 12 / 13) + Hmother) / 2

```
            if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")) {
            childHeightInch = (((monHeightInch + (monHeightFeet * 12)) * 13 / 12) + (dadHeightInch + (dadHeightFeet * 12)) / 2);
            childHeightFeet = childHeightInch / 12;
            childHeightInch = childHeightInch % 12;
        } else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")) {
            childHeightInch = (((dadHeightInch + (dadHeightFeet * 12)) * 12 / 13) + (monHeightInch + (monHeightFeet * 12)) / 2);
            childHeightFeet = childHeightInch / 12;
            childHeightInch = childHeightInch % 12;
```

Comment: If you're using integer math there will be some small inaccuracies. Perhaps you should use doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some Brackets,it is only dividing dad height by 2

```
childHeightInch = (((((monHeightInch + (monHeightFeet * 12)) * 13) / 12) + (dadHeightInch + (dadHeightFeet * 12))) / 2);

childHeightInch = (((((dadHeightInch + (dadHeightFeet * 12)) * 12) / 13) + (monHeightInch + (monHeightFeet * 12))) / 2);
```

Comment: Also the number 13 is used when the calculation is done in centimeters, as he is doing it in inches, he needs to convert the 13cm to inches (~5.11in)

Comment: @ItsMeNaira No, the numbers in the formula are dimensionless.  It'll be 13 whether he measures in inches or in centimetres.

Comment: Why are they dimensionless? If you search up how to estimate children’s heights it specifically says “add/subtract (based on gender) 5inches or 13 cm”.

Comment: @ItsMeNaira if you don't believe me, try it out.  If you replace 13 with 5 in the first formula, you get tiny children.  If you replace 13 with 5 in the second formula, you get giants.  If you replace both the 12 and the 13 in either of the two formulas, then the two changes cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do all the calculations on one line, then no matter how you do it, you'll end up with far too many parentheses.  The result is that it will be difficult to read the code accurately, and you'll make mistakes.  As indeed you have done.

Don't write any parentheses that you don't mathematically need.  And consider calculating the total heights of Mum and Dad separately first, as shown below.

```
int dadsHeightTotal = dadsHeightInches + dadsHeightFeet * 12;
int mumsHeightTotal = mumsHeightInches + mumsHeightFeet * 12;

if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
    childsHeightTotal = ( mumsHeightTotal * 13 / 12 + dadsHeightTotal ) / 2;
} else {
    childsHeightTotal = ( dadsHeightTotal * 12 / 13 + mumsHeightTotal ) / 2;
}

childsHeightFeet = childsHeightTotal / 12;
childsHeightInches = childsHeightTotal % 12;
```